# Select two characters from string in LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I have to convert an hexadecimal string starting with `0x` or an hexadecimal string converted with `BitConverter` to a `byte` array. For this I use this function which works very well:

```
public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(this string s)
{
    if (s.StartsWith("0x"))
    {
        var ret = new byte[(s.Length - 2) / 2];
        for (int i = 2; i < s.Length; i += 2)
        {
            ret[(i - 2) / 2] = Convert.ToByte(string.Concat(s[i], s[i + 1]), 16);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    else
        return s.Split('-').Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16)).ToArray();
}
```

example input, coming from a sort of a network device (think of it as a message logged with wireshark ) :

```
byte[] data1 = "0x020206000000022800A601585E40".ConvertToByteArray();
byte[] data2 = "02-02-06-00-00-00-02-28-00-A6-01-58-5E-40".ConvertToByteArray();
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(data1, data2);
```

Now I would like to understand how to write the first possibility (starts with `0x`) in LINQ to get rid of this 1990ish for loop.

Is there a way to Select two characters at the same time, or is there a more elegant way then mine?

Comment: Can u share input of function ConvertToByteArray?

Comment: Try following :             string input = "0x0123456789ABCDEF";
            ushort[] output = input.Skip(2).Select((x, i) => new { x = x, i = i }).GroupBy(x => x.i / 2).Select(x => (ushort)((x.FirstOrDefault().x << 8) + (x.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().x))).ToArray();

Comment: Or if you need to parse character to hex :               string input = "0x0123456789ABCDEF";
            ushort[] output = input.Skip(2).Select((x, i) => new { x = byte.Parse(x.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), i = i }).GroupBy(x => x.i / 2).Select(x => (ushort)((x.FirstOrDefault().x << 8) + (x.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().x))).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng this wont work for me as I need to have a byte array. The data is form a network resource

Comment: I was just following your code where you went from string to ushort.  Not sure why your code had two steps of going to ushort and then to byte[]. I assumed you need ed ushort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the linq equivalent of your loop regardless of any other consideration:

```
if (s.StartsWith("0x"))
{
    return
    s.Skip(2)
     .Select((x,i) => new {index = i, value = x})
     .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 2)
     .Select(grp => string.Join("", grp.Select(x=>x.value)))
     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x,16))
     .ToArray();
}
```

But this seems to be a solution to your consideration of not having a 90ish code:

```
public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(this string s)
{
    string tmp = s.Replace("0x","").Replace("-","");
    tmp = Regex.Replace(tmp, ".{2}", "$0-");
    return tmp.Split('-').Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well i think first you can have a look at this

Using @jdweng sample input.

```
string input = "0x0123456789ABCDE".Replace("0x", string.Empty);
long intValue = long.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Now if you have long you can convert it to byte[] easly.

```
byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
```

I know it it's not LINQ solution to your problem but it's clean and simple.

Comment: Please keep in mind that maximum hex number that could be parsed properly to int is "7FFFFFFF". Depends of your needs I would consider using long.Parse which allow you to use bigger hex numbers. Besides that, I think this is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: You could also test jdweng's comment in the question and if it works add it to your question (quoting him/her).

Comment: As the input is some kind of network traffic (so its length vary a lot) this wont work for me

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

After reading OP's comment, I see he wants to be able to consume hex strings of an arbitrary length.  I'd be tempted to use an iterator function to return your hex pairs, to match the result of your split.  Then you can feed either enumerable through the same conversion, like so:

```
public byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string s)
{
    IEnumerable<string> query = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    if (s.StartsWith("0x"))
    {
        query = IterateHexPairs(s.Substring(2));
    }
    else
    {
        query = s.Split('-');
    }

    return query.Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16)).ToArray();

    IEnumerable<string> IterateHexPairs(string hexLiteral)
    {
        char? previousNibble = null;

        foreach (var nibble in hexLiteral)
        {
            if (previousNibble != null)
            {
                yield return new string(new char[] { previousNibble.Value, nibble });
                previousNibble = null;
            }
            else
            {
                previousNibble = nibble;   
            }                               
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids having to duplicate your conversion logic, as they both get fed from an IEnumerable.  The only difference is the source of the IEnumerable.  Change the code that gives you the enumerable as you see fit.  I thought an Iterator function would be more maintainable, but you could bodge a Linq query to achieve the same result, like this:

```
public byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string s)
{
    IEnumerable<string> query = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    if (s.StartsWith("0x"))
    {        
        // omit the 0x
        query = s.Skip(2)
        // get the char and index, so we can pair them up
                 .Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i })
        // group them into pairs
                 .GroupBy(o => o.Index / 2)
        // select them as new strings, so they can be converted
                 .Select(g => new string(g.Select(o => o.Char).ToArray()));
    }
    else
    {
        query = s.Split('-');
    }

    return query.Select(b => Convert.ToByte(b, 16)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I want to use low-level information as it is a low-level input source (network traffic)

Comment: @MaxR. I've updated my answer to address your feedback.  It will now take a hex string of arbitrary length.  I've illustrated 2 approaches, one using Linq, and the other using an Iterator function.